# How can i disable full screen button on JW Player 6?

Tags: fullscreen, jwplayer

I tried the following code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('video').setup({
        height: 267,
        width: 475,
        autostart: true,
        enableFullscreen: 'false',
        playlist: [{
            sources: [
                { file: "1.mp4" },
                { file: "1.flv" },
                { file: "2.webm" }
            ]
        }]
    });
</script>
```

But not working `enableFullscreen: 'false'`. What is the way to do that?
Sorry for my english.

---

### UPDATE

I create my custom skin, but i can't hide the fullscreen button on JW Player.

```
<skin version="2.0" name="user92" author="user92" target="6.0">
    <components>
        <component name="controlbar">
            <elements>
                <element name="fullscreenButton" value="false" />
            </elements>
        </component>        
    </components>
</skin>
```

I have error on loading skin. What is the param that i have to set for hide only fullscreenbutton?. No all controlbar.

---

### LAST UPDATE

OK. For hide the fullscreen button with the skin. You should assemble all controlbar, Omitting buttonfullscreen options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JW Player 6, removing the fullscreen button can be done via our skinning model:

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28847/building-jw-player-skins
http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28849/skin-xml-reference

The SDK is available here - http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/

Basically, in the skin XML file, there is a section for the fullscreen/normalscreen button on the controlbar, which you can remove / comment out.

This section can be removed / commented out:

```
<element name="fullscreenButton" src="fullscreenButton.png" />
                <element name="fullscreenButtonOver" src="fullscreenButtonOver.png" />
                <element name="normalscreenButton" src="normalscreenButton.png" />
                <element name="normalscreenButtonOver" src="normalscreenButtonOver.png" />
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I disabled the fullscreen button. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Now.. Can I share the JW Player with the video file on facebook wall user by meta tags? Or it is not posible?

Comment: I update my question. When i apply the custom skin with any png image in the `src` of element `fullscreenbutton` all control bar dissapear.

Comment: Np! JW6 won't work in Facebook OG tags, but JW5 will - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/blog/19150/publish-your-videos-to-facebook-with-a-jw-player, regarding your issue wit the custom skin, do you have a link?

Comment: Not problem now. Reading the documentation I found that I should arm all the controlbar.

Comment: where i can download JW Player version 5?.. I want download the version 5.9

Comment: I found mediaplayer 5.9 on Tag Browser.. Is it Jw Player version 5.9?

Comment: JW Player is wonderful. So I decided to buy the JW Player 5.9 and 6. As I can buy both?

Comment: Yes, if you buy V6, we can send you V5 as well, just email us after the purchase.

Comment: Thanks, I'll buy the JW Player 6 soon. With this purchase, I'll obtain JW Player version 5.9 too, right? I just need to send an email to you after the purchase? Or What should I do?

Comment: Np, yes, just send us an email after purchase.

Comment: OK. I just bought the JW Player 6! I will send to you an email for the JW Player 5.9.

Comment: Do i send email to premiumsupport? Or exist other special email for do this?

Comment: Done! I just send to you the email.

Answer (score 2):

Hide full screen button in JWPlayer 7:
$('.jw-icon-fullscreen').hide();

Comment: Confirm the same for JWPlayer 8

Answer (score 1):

You can just hide it by changing the fullscreen button's z-index.

```
jwplayer('video').setup({
        height: 267,
        width: 475,
        autostart: true,
        enableFullscreen: 'false',
        playlist: [{
            sources: [
                { file: "1.mp4" },
                { file: "1.flv" },
                { file: "2.webm" }
            ]
        }]
    }).onReady(function () {
            $(".jwfullscreen").css("z-index", "-1");
        });
```

Comment: Actually a good idea. but note that the class `.jwfullscreen` is changed in latets version to `jw-icon-fullscreen`